# Is general anesthesia an independent risk factor for perioperative ischemia?

Tags: surgery, anesthesia

An [study](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/10691229/) mentions that anesthesia with surgery increases the risk of a ischemic injury 30 days after a procedure.

It is unclear to me however whether general anesthesia itself increases the risk of ischemia during the operation or in the immediate postoperative period?

Comment: They looked at strokes occurring during the 30 days _following_ the surgery, so they weren't counting strokes that occurred _during_ the procedure.  One thing to consider is that surgery requiring general anesthesia is generally more major than surgery that doesn't require it. All I can conclude from that study is that people who undergo major surgery are more prone to suffer strokes, which I don't find surprising or enlightening.

Comment: I know and you're right but that's is why I was wondering if it's the surgery (and requiring period of being bed-ridden) that increases the risks and the type of anesthesia is just the necessary accompanying factor. There are minor short operations that can be done either in local or general like a septoplasty for example. So is a septo under local safer (ischemia-wise) than a septo under general?

Comment: There's a lot of back and forth research in this area; there are some people convinced that anesthesia is the cause of all sorts of ills (post-surgical cognitive decline, strokes, general morbidity). But, indeed, most of the evidence is observational and not experimental, and there are huge confounding issues. The problem is that anesthesia is used for a *reason*, and cases without anesthesia are always different than cases with.

Comment: that's true, any study trying to assess this needs to find patients of matched age, surgery, health status etc and then compare cases where the only difference was the type of anesthesia and do so in large enough numbers so it is statistically significant. I don't know if that's even possible tbh

Comment: @agiro Even matching on those things doesn't quite work, because the choice of anesthesia is dependent on the particulars of the case.